# Using identity comparison with a boolean literal error

Tags: python-3.x, automation, network-programming

```
cmd =[]
def SetOSPFInterface(**kwargs):
    attribute_map = {
        'priority': 'priority',
        'passive': 'passive',
        'interface_type': 'interface-type',
        'metric': 'metric',
    }
    for attr, cfg_expr in attribute_map.items():
        attr_value = kwargs.get(attr) if kwargs.get(attr) is not False else None
        print(attr_value, attr)
        if attr_value is not None:
            if isinstance(attr_value, bool):
                attr_expr = ''
            else:
                attr_expr = ' %s' % attr_value
            cmd.append('set %s%s' % (cfg_expr, attr_expr))

    return cmd
print(SetOSPFInterface(priority=0))
```

I am trying to set "priority value to 0", the current implementation is throwing boolean literal error(Using identity comparison with a boolean literal error, this is a python lint error. Which says its not good practise to use 'is' , 'is not' with boolean values). So if I change the condition to `attr_value = kwargs.get(attr) if kwargs.get(attr) and isinstance(kwargs.get(attr), bool) else None` then priority Value '0' will be blocked.

Comment: Fix your formatting and also post the whole error message please.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do it might be to make use of `dict.get(key, default)`, and `or`, which would lead a falsy value to become another value of your choosing:

```
attr_value = kwargs.get(attr, None) or None
```

Comment: This will not help the priority variable when value is sent as '0'